# Options menu (actionbar) not showing

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I have an Activity that displays a feed item, and it has a context menu to complete actions like sharing, adding to your favorites etc. I have moved the items from the context menu to options menu, so it can the actions can be performed directly from the actionbar. But the options menu is not showing up in the actionbar (it did show up before). I haven not added any actions to the items yet, but they should be displayed in the optionsmenu though.

FeedItemActivity:

```
 package com.mfavez.android.feedgoal;

 someimports....
 import com.mfavez.android.feedgoal.storage.SharedPreferencesHelper;


 public class FeedItemActivity extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "FeedItemActivity";
private static final int KILL_ACTIVITY_CODE = 1;

private DbFeedAdapter mDbFeedAdapter;
private long mItemId = -1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //only show bar for honeycomb and over
    int currentAPIVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.show();
    }
    //end of actionbardisplay

    mDbFeedAdapter = new DbFeedAdapter(this);
    mDbFeedAdapter.open();

    TrackerAnalyticsHelper.createTracker(this);

    mItemId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(DbSchema.ItemSchema._ID) : -1;

    if (mItemId == -1) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
        mItemId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(DbSchema.ItemSchema._ID) : -1;
    }

    Item item = mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId);
    if (item.isFavorite())
        setContentView(R.layout.item_favorite);
    else
        setContentView(R.layout.item_notfavorite);

    /*
     * To test ads in emulator, remove ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" in layout
    if (SharedPreferencesHelper.useAdmob(this)) {
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("adView", "id", this.getPackageName());
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(resourceId);
        //AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        adView.loadAd(request);
    }
    */
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

    TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(FeedItemActivity.this,LOG_TAG,"Link_Title",mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId).getLink().toString(),1);
            adjustLinkableTextColor (v);
            startItemWebActivity();
        }
    });

    TextView channel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.channel);
    channel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Feed feed = mDbFeedAdapter.getFeed(mDbFeedAdapter.getItemFeedId(mItemId));
            String channelHomepage = feed.getHomePage().toString();
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(FeedItemActivity.this,LOG_TAG,"Link_Channel",channelHomepage,1);
            adjustLinkableTextColor (v);
            if (SharedPreferencesHelper.isOnline(FeedItemActivity.this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(channelHomepage));
                startActivity(intent);
            } else
                showDialog(SharedPreferencesHelper.DIALOG_NO_CONNECTION);
        }
    });

    Button read_online = (Button)findViewById(R.id.read);
    read_online.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(FeedItemActivity.this,LOG_TAG,"Button_ReadOnline",mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId).getLink().toString(),1);
            startItemWebActivity();
        }
    });

    registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.item));
}

private void startItemWebActivity() {
    if (SharedPreferencesHelper.isOnline(FeedItemActivity.this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FeedItemActivity.this, FeedWebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DbSchema.ItemSchema._ID, mItemId);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else
        showDialog(SharedPreferencesHelper.DIALOG_NO_CONNECTION);
}

private void adjustLinkableTextColor (View v) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) v;
    textView.setTextColor(R.color.color2);

}

private void displayItemView() {
    if (mItemId != -1) {
        Item item = mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView channelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.channel);
        TextView pubdateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pubdate);
        TextView contentView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        if (titleView != null)
            titleView.setText(item.getTitle());
        if (channelView != null) {
            Feed feed = mDbFeedAdapter.getFeed(mDbFeedAdapter.getItemFeedId(mItemId));
            if (feed != null)
                channelView.setText(feed.getTitle());
        } 
        if (pubdateView != null) {
            //DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(getResources().getText(R.string.pubdate_format_pattern);
            //pubdateView.setText(df.format(item.getPubdate()));
            CharSequence formattedPubdate = DateFormat.format(getResources().getText(R.string.pubdate_format_pattern), item.getPubdate());
            pubdateView.setText(formattedPubdate);
        }
        if (contentView != null) {
            String content_description = item.getContent();
            if (content_description == null)
                content_description = item.getDescription();
            if (content_description != null)
                //contentView.setText(content_description,TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                contentView.setText(content_description);
        }

        // set item as read (case when item is displayed from next/previous contextual menu or buttons)
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DbSchema.ItemSchema.COLUMN_READ, DbSchema.ON);
        mDbFeedAdapter.updateItem(mItemId, values, null);

        TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackPageView(this,"/offlineItemView");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    TrackerAnalyticsHelper.startTracker(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    displayItemView();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    TrackerAnalyticsHelper.stopTracker(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDbFeedAdapter.close();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong(DbSchema.ItemSchema._ID, mItemId);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
//Problems is around here I think!
//---------------------------------------------------------------


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    Item item = mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId);

    if (SharedPreferencesHelper.isDynamicMode(this)) {

        if (item != null) {
            long feedId = mDbFeedAdapter.getItemFeedId(mItemId);
            boolean isFirstItem = false;
            boolean isLastItem = false;
            if (mItemId == mDbFeedAdapter.getFirstItem(feedId).getId())
                isFirstItem = true;
            else if (mItemId == mDbFeedAdapter.getLastItem(feedId).getId())
                isLastItem = true;

            if (item.isFavorite()) {
                if (isFirstItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_notfav_next, menu);
                else if (isLastItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_notfav_prev, menu);
                else
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_notfav_next_prev, menu);
            } else {
                if (isFirstItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_fav_next, menu);
                else if (isLastItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_fav_prev, menu);
                else
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_fav_next_prev, menu);
            }
        }

        MenuItem channelsMenuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_opt_channels);
        channelsMenuItem.setIntent(new Intent(this,FeedChannelsActivity.class));
    } else {

        if (item != null) {
            long feedId = mDbFeedAdapter.getItemFeedId(mItemId);
            boolean isFirstItem = false;
            boolean isLastItem = false;
            if (mItemId == mDbFeedAdapter.getFirstItem(feedId).getId())
                isFirstItem = true;
            else if (mItemId == mDbFeedAdapter.getLastItem(feedId).getId())
                isLastItem = true;

            if (item.isFavorite()) {
                if (isFirstItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_notfav_next, menu);
                else if (isLastItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_notfav_prev, menu);
                else
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_notfav_next_prev, menu);
            } else {
                if (isFirstItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_fav_next, menu);
                else if (isLastItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_fav_prev, menu);
                else
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_dyn_offline_fav_next_prev, menu);
            }
        }

        // Channels menu item
        if (mDbFeedAdapter.getFeeds().size() > 1) {
            MenuItem channelsMenuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_opt_channels);
            SubMenu subMenu = channelsMenuItem.getSubMenu();

            List<Feed> feeds = mDbFeedAdapter.getFeeds();
            Iterator<Feed> feedIterator = feeds.iterator();
            Feed feed = null;
            MenuItem channelSubMenuItem = null;
            Intent intent = null;
            int order = 0;
            while (feedIterator.hasNext()) {
                feed = feedIterator.next();
                channelSubMenuItem = subMenu.add(SharedPreferencesHelper.CHANNEL_SUBMENU_GROUP, Menu.NONE, order, feed.getTitle());

                if (feed.getId() == SharedPreferencesHelper.getPrefTabFeedId(this, mDbFeedAdapter.getFirstFeed().getId()))
                    channelSubMenuItem.setChecked(true);

                intent = new Intent(this, FeedTabActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DbSchema.FeedSchema._ID, feed.getId());
                channelSubMenuItem.setIntent(intent);

                order++;
            }

            subMenu.setGroupCheckable(SharedPreferencesHelper.CHANNEL_SUBMENU_GROUP, true, true);
        } else {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_opt_channels);
        }
    }

    // Home menu item
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_opt_home);
    menuItem.setIntent(new Intent(this, FeedTabActivity.class));     

    // Preferences menu item
    MenuItem preferencesMenuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_opt_preferences);
    preferencesMenuItem.setIntent(new Intent(this,FeedPrefActivity.class));

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      //using icon to go up in honeycomb and higher
       switch (item.getItemId()) 
       {        
          case android.R.id.home:            
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, FeedTabActivity.class);            
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
             startActivity(intent);            
             return true;        
          default:            
       }
       //thats it
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_opt_home:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"OptionMenu_Home","Home",1);
            // Kill the FeedTabActivity that started this FeedItemActivity, because tab channel id may have changed and wouldn't be correct (wouldn't be the initial FeedTabActivity channel id) if back button is pressed
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            startActivity(item.getIntent());
            //finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_opt_channels:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"OptionMenu_Channels","Channels",1);
            if (SharedPreferencesHelper.isDynamicMode(this)) {
                // Kill the FeedTabActivity that started this FeedItemActivity, because tab channel id may have changed and wouldn't be correct (wouldn't be the initial FeedTabActivity channel id) if back button is pressed
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                startActivityForResult(item.getIntent(),KILL_ACTIVITY_CODE);
            } else {
                //do nothing, default case will be handled
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_opt_preferences:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"OptionMenu_Preferences","Preferences",1);
            startActivity(item.getIntent());
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_opt_about:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"OptionMenu_AboutDialog","About",1);
            showDialog(SharedPreferencesHelper.DIALOG_ABOUT);
            return true;
        default:
            if (item.getGroupId() == SharedPreferencesHelper.CHANNEL_SUBMENU_GROUP) {
                // Kill the FeedTabActivity that started this FeedItemActivity, because tab channel id is now changing and won't be correct (won't be the initial FeedTabActivity channel id) if back button is pressed
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                startActivity(item.getIntent());
                //finish();
                return true;
            }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case KILL_ACTIVITY_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                finish();
            break;
        }
}

public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    if (v.getId() == R.id.item) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle (R.string.ctx_menu_title);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        Item item = mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId);

        if (item != null) {
            long feedId = mDbFeedAdapter.getItemFeedId(mItemId);
            boolean isFirstItem = false;
            boolean isLastItem = false;
            if (mItemId == mDbFeedAdapter.getFirstItem(feedId).getId())
                isFirstItem = true;
            else if (mItemId == mDbFeedAdapter.getLastItem(feedId).getId())
                isLastItem = true;

            if (item.isFavorite()) {
                if (isFirstItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_offline_notfav_next, menu);
                else if (isLastItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_offline_notfav_prev, menu);
                else
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_offline_notfav_next_prev, menu);
            } else {
                if (isFirstItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_offline_fav_next, menu);
                else if (isLastItem)
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_offline_fav_prev, menu);
                else
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.ctx_menu_item_offline_fav_next_prev, menu);
            }
        }
    }
}


public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    Item item = mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId);
    ImageView favView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fav);
    ContentValues values = null;
    Intent intent = null;
    long feedId = -1;

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.read_online:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"ContextMenu_ReadOnline",item.getLink().toString(),1);
            startItemWebActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.add_fav:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"ContextMenu_AddFavorite",item.getLink().toString(),1);
            //item.favorite();
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DbSchema.ItemSchema.COLUMN_FAVORITE, DbSchema.ON);
            mDbFeedAdapter.updateItem(mItemId, values, null);
            favView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_fav_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.remove_fav:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"ContextMenu_RemoveFavorite",item.getLink().toString(),1);
            //item.unfavorite();
            Date now = new Date();
            long diffTime = now.getTime() - item.getPubdate().getTime();
            long maxTime = SharedPreferencesHelper.getPrefMaxHours(this) * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Max hours expressed in milliseconds
            // test if item has expired
            if (maxTime > 0 && diffTime > maxTime) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.remove_fav_confirmation)
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put(DbSchema.ItemSchema.COLUMN_FAVORITE, DbSchema.OFF);
                                ImageView favView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fav);
                                favView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_fav);
                                mDbFeedAdapter.updateItem(mItemId, values, null);
                                Toast.makeText(FeedItemActivity.this, R.string.remove_fav_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                builder.create().show();
            } else {
                values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(DbSchema.ItemSchema.COLUMN_FAVORITE, DbSchema.OFF);
                mDbFeedAdapter.updateItem(mItemId, values, null);
                favView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_fav);
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.remove_fav_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.next:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"ContextMenu_NextItem",item.getLink().toString(),1);
            feedId = mDbFeedAdapter.getItemFeedId(mItemId);
            intent = new Intent(this, FeedItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DbSchema.ItemSchema._ID, mDbFeedAdapter.getNextItemId(feedId, mItemId));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.previous:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"ContextMenu_PreviousItem",item.getLink().toString(),1);
            feedId = mDbFeedAdapter.getItemFeedId(mItemId);
            intent = new Intent(this, FeedItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DbSchema.ItemSchema._ID, mDbFeedAdapter.getPreviousItemId(feedId, mItemId));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.share:
            TrackerAnalyticsHelper.trackEvent(this,LOG_TAG,"ContextMenu_Share",item.getLink().toString(),1);
            item = mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId);
            if (item != null) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, String.format(getString(R.string.share_subject), getString(R.string.app_name)));
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, item.getTitle() + " " + item.getLink().toString());
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share)));
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    CharSequence title = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    View dialogLayout = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;
    switch (id) {
        case SharedPreferencesHelper.DIALOG_ABOUT:
            //title = getResources().getText(R.string.app_name) + " - " + getResources().getText(R.string.version) + " " + SharedPreferencesHelper.getVersionName(this);
            title = getString(R.string.app_name) + " - " + getString(R.string.version) + " " + SharedPreferencesHelper.getVersionName(this);

            /*
             * Without cancel button
            dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_about);
            dialog.setTitle(title);
            */
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_about, null);
            TextView childView = null;
            if (getString(R.string.website).equals("")) {
                childView = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.website);
                childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (getString(R.string.email).equals("")) {
                childView = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.email);
                childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (getString(R.string.contact).equals("")) {
                childView = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.contact);
                childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (getString(R.string.powered).equals("")) {
                childView = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.powered);
                childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setView(dialogLayout)
                   .setTitle(title)
                   .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog)
                   .setNeutralButton(R.string.close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;
        case SharedPreferencesHelper.DIALOG_NO_CONNECTION:
            title = getString(R.string.error);
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_no_connection, null);
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setView(dialogLayout)
                   .setTitle(title)
                   .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog)
                   .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
        }
      return dialog;
   }
 }
```

My old FeedItemActivity:
http://pastebin.com/4rV9uq15

I hopy somebody can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: What happens when you press the MENU button of your device or emulator?

Comment: On my nexus 4, no menu button is displayed which means nothing would happen if there was any. But I'll test on the emulator

Comment: Just tested it, unfortunately nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: I'll try it today, but I think it I'll not work because in every case a different options menu layout file must be loaded, as you can see a little be neath getmenuinflator, i inflate a different menu depending on if its the first, last, favorite or dynamic item. But I think the problem has something to do with the inflating.

Answer (score 0):

if u want set your menus in action bar at bottom use this in manifest.

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

or if u want to set that in top action bar u must use an xml,otherwise it will show only if menu is clicked

Comment: The actionbar is being displayed, and the options menu worked with the actionbar set before setcontentview, to be sure I've just tried your solution but unfortunately no change

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out, but the problem is is that the menu button in the right-top-corner (http://goo.gl/uSt8V) is not being displayed at all, in fact nothing except the title & logo is being displayed in the actionbar.

Comment: Sorry if not getting make sure that your conditions work as u expected may be a bug, debug all of it

Comment: @Mark029348 do you have a hard MEN|U button on the device you are testing on?

Comment: On the emulator yes, on my phone no, but I had the 3 dots displayed in the upper right corner (http://goo.gl/uSt8V) in the actionbar in the old FeedItemActivity. And the 3 dots should still be there to show the menu in the new FeedItemActivity, but they aren't and that's why my question is: "why is the options menu in the actionbar not showing"

Comment: i think there's not enough space to show that,give preference to options menu and remove that phone logo from there just for testing

Comment: I understand your question but the 3 dots are an overflow menu. They won't show if you have a device with a menu button or if you don't have items that won't fit on the screen unless you explicitly tell them to show in the overflow menu in your menu xml

Comment: @codeMagic "They won't show if you have a device with a menu button" thats wrong ,even if you have a hard menu button action bar menu will show everything that you add.

Comment: There is enough space in the actionbar to display the overflow menu, and it should display the menu, but I made some mistake in my code somewhere (I marked where it should be around) but I can't find it. If my code was correct (like the one in the pastebin) it displays the overflow menu button in the actionbar.

Comment: @Arju how do you figure? Are you talking about the overflow button (3 dots on the right). I believe I am correct unless you are using ActionbarSherlock

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you never inflated your menu here

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
Item item = mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId);
```

you create your inflater but don't use it. Change it to

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate((R.menu.mainmenu, menu);    // you forgot this line here where mainmenu is your menu xml
Item item = mDbFeedAdapter.getItem(mItemId);
```

Comment: I am using my inflator, but I'm using it a few lines later, I'm trying to load a different menu layout file if item is favorite, dynamic, static, first item, last item etc. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but I don't know where.